# Starting a service from another Apk from a ResolveInfo

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-service-binding

I'm creating an app that reads every Service that has an IntentFilter that matches a custom action by using this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION);
List<ResolveInfo> infos = getActivity().getPackageManager()
                .queryIntentServices(intent, 0);
```

I have no problem retrieving the Services, but when I try to bind them to the current Activity, my IBinder implementation is not passed to `onServiceConnected(ComponentName, IBinder)`. Instead, a `BinderProxy`is being passed.

How can I get my `LocalBinder` from that `BinderProxy`?

EDIT:

Here's my implementation:

```
public abstract class LocalService extends Service {

    private LocalBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {

        public LocalService getServiceInstance() {
            return LocalService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    public abstract List<Category> getInitialCategories();

    public abstract void onObjectSelected(Item object,
            LocalCallback callback);

}
```

What I want to do is to be able to call the last 2 methods from other people's implementations of my LocalService.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do that.

You're binding to a service *in a different process*. It would be impossible to get a reference to your actual `LocalBinder` instance, because processes cannot share object instances.

---

I haven't tested this scenario myself, but according to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Creating) if you need IPC for Services you have two alternatives, either a [Messenger](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger) or [AIDL](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html). The first one seems much simpler.

> If you need your interface to work across different processes, you can
>   create an interface for the service with a Messenger. In this manner,
>   the service defines a Handler that responds to different types of
>   Message objects. This Handler is the basis for a Messenger that can
>   then share an IBinder with the client, allowing the client to send
>   commands to the service using Message objects. Additionally, the
>   client can define a Messenger of its own so the service can send
>   messages back.
>
> This is the simplest way to perform interprocess communication (IPC),
>   because the Messenger queues all requests into a single thread so that
>   you don't have to design your service to be thread-safe.

Comment: If I can't use binding, how can I communicate between my `Services` and the app? it is imperative for them to be in different apks.

Comment: I have edited my question to give more info about what I want to achieve.

Comment: @santirivera92 Edited answer, though it's fairly generic because I haven't actually used this. The example in the docs seems to be essential your use case, however. I hope it's helpful.

Comment: Ok, gonna try now. I'll report back!